# Issues making a stacked div responsive on another div with an image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I need to achieve this effect.

I am using bootstrap by the way

https://gyazo.com/089764ced3250e52c184b16f991214e0

This is my initial code but I have no idea how to position it, I have tried everything and it still isn't responsive to the window. How best could I do this, thanks :).

```
<div class="row" id="banner-top-row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="banner-top-col">
        <img src="img/banner-top.png" id="banner-top" class="img-responsive"/>
        <div class="banner-information">
            <h4> For More Information.... </h4>
            <h1> Contact Us </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I am not able to get what you exactly want but If I am getting right that you are expecting to be your image and content to be in center, without compromising responsive design. 
Please check out it, if this snippet of code could help you out

http://jsbin.com/binusu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Ye sorta, like the banner-top image stretches across my page fine and is responsive, but I need to add this box on top of the image as shown in the picture and make this responsive as well :). Sorry just to clarify, the content box needs to be to the left side of the image as shown :)

Comment: Ye that's it :), Thanks a lot